# How to update my setting to use part function of Django?

Tags: python, django

My Project structure as below :

```
├── conf
│   ├── client.json
│   ├── settings.py
├── logs
│   └── management.log
├── dbs
│   └── models.py
└── src
    └── main.py
```

In `settings.py` I add `dbs` in to `INSTALLED_APPS`

`settings.py`

```
...

INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'dbs',
]
...
```

`models.py`

```
# coding: utf-8

from django.db import models

class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
```

I setted in `main.py` at started followed some opnions from websites:

```
import sys, os
import json
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import logging

import django

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR ,'conf'))
sys.path.append(os.path.join(BASE_DIR ,'dbs'))

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')

django.setup()

from django.conf import settings
from models import User
```

But error `No module named 'dbs'` showed, how can I correct my codes to use db, log part of `Django`

Tnahsks.

Comment: Instead of naming the directory as 'dbs' name it as 'models' and have an __init__.py with all the class imports. For more info : https://williamsbdev.com/posts/django-models-directory/